# problemas instalar composer

Tags: php, composer

tuve que desintalar el composer de mi maquina para instalarlo una vez mas, pero mi pide poner un proxy porque mi navegacion es atravez de proxys y este no me deja cambiarlo, como puedo cambiar esa configuracion del proxy. estoy usando Xampp 7.2.3

Comment: Talvez esta pregunta te ayude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307600/php-composer-behind-http-proxy

Comment: intento usar el comando de set pero no se me cambia la configuracion y cuando intento instalar el composer.exe me sigue apareciendo la configuracion antigua del proxy viejo

Comment: intenta con las otras respuestas